# Failed to find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 3.1.1
My app was based on the firebase. I added the dependencies what they gave to me. But there's an error which I'm not figured.

**Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1.**

I added these dependencies,
1) build.gradle (Module:app) file.
2) build.gradle (Top-level build).

And I updated all SDKs and tried to sync. But it fails.[Image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM915.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show your build.gradle files.

Comment: Dude, I figured what's wrong with it. I missed; 
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
Thanks dude..